# Username/password autofill on UITextField only fills out the selected custom view conforming to UITextInput

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, autofill, uitextinput

I've been fiddling with autofill for my signup flow on iOS, and I can't seem to get it to work perfectly.

I have a custom view that has a `UITextField` as one of the properties and I build all my text fields as instances of that custom view.

When I first made it, I didn't know I was supposed to conform to `UITextInput` to make autofill work, but autofill already *almost* worked great on everything except when `textContentType = .newPassword`. What was working was that **I could tap the password manager when logging in and iOS would fill out BOTH the username & password fields for me**, EXCEPT for the `.newPassword` field which didn't work at all or fill new passwords.

When I conformed to `UITextInput`, the `.newPassword` text field kinda worked in that it would let me open the password manager...however, **all text fields now only fill out the selected `UITextField`, and never any other one.** Ahhh I thought I had it!

This is far from desirable, since a user could create a password and only the username would be filled out, or vice versa. Plus, when logging in, you have to enter your password manager twice for the username + password.

Any tips for making this work? Thank you!

PS - It seemed that conforming to `UITextInput` was [just boilerplate code anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70089128/easily-conform-to-uitextinput-when-i-have-a-custom-view-with-a-uitextfield-prope) since I was already using a UITextField but just wrapped in a parent UIView...which was confusing but alright.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. You said your password field wasn't being filled out and then you contradict yourself by saying that it works. "Working great in that I could tap the password manager when logging in and iOS would fill out BOTH the username & password fields for me" <- That's what its supposed to do. What is the issue here?

Comment: It's very confusing I know. I have reworded it a bit to hopefully clarify. To your specific point it was working great EXCEPT for the `.newPassword` text type which wasn't working at all.

Comment: You must make sure you have associated domains set up in order for iOS to suggest a randomly generated password. This also means you must have a working website that hosts some specific app data, more details here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

Comment: Yes, I did all that. Still broken. I've also used a few apps on the app store that seem to have the same problem. I think it's an Apple bug. (problem I've ended up with is that when I use password manager to fill out form it only fills one at a time, but the password is recommending now)